# How to get Google Sheets bound code.js to read and act on JavaScript from an uncontained remote .js file?

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets on a GSuite Drive that I own. This Google Sheets has a bound code.js script file. I also have a remote .js file that contains the function I want to execute on my sheet (in a normal situation this function would simply reside within the code.js file).

I have created button images on the sheet that trigger scripts inside the code.js file. When I click a button my code.js script executes successfully:

- the button triggers the code.js script which fetches the remote js file via URL and stores it into a variable (this remote file could just as easily be a text file but to keep my OCD in check I named it .js)
- I use `console.log(variable)` to confirm that indeed the entire.js file has been retrieved.
- I use `eval(variable)` but nothing happens

If I paste the `console.log(variable)` output directly into the code.js file, it works as expected.

Is `eval()` the wrong call? Or is it not as powerful as I am hoping?

```
function countStuffButton() { //Counts the number of current stuffs
    var url = "http://my.website/js/countStuff.js";
    var javascript = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    console.log(javascript);
    eval(javascript);  
}
```

`console.log` that I get back:

```
function countStuff() {
    // bunch of code that works when paste directly into code.js
}
```

What I am hoping/expecting is that I can store a JavaScript function on a server in a .js file and then fetch the content of the function to be processed locally within the code.js bound script of my Google Sheets, resulting in a Google Sheets that is a pure "front end" making script and HTML calls to files that I fully own and control on my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `eval(code)` function you know it executes JavaScript code from a string.

However `code` needs to be a string that contains the JavaScript **expression to be evaluated** or **the statements to be executed**.

In your case the variable `javascript` contains the countStuff function declaration.

Function declarations are statements as they perform the action of creating a variable whose value is that of the function.

### To fix that you can:

1. Change your remote countStuff function to become an [immediately-invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) :

```
function countStuff() {
//bunch of code that works when paste directly into code.js
}()
```

2. Invoke the function yourself `eval('new ' + javascript + '()')`

To understand this second scenario and why new is needed have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/336868/4807777).

3. `countStuff` becomes available so you can also call it after eval()'s execution like `countStuff()`